# checking whether library exist via preprocessor

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

There are two libraries `zconf.h` and `unistd.h` which are used to at least to get `pid` of the process. I generally test my code on Mac OSX and Ubuntu 18.04 in which they use `zconf.h` preferably(compiler offers `zconf.h` in lieu of `unistd.h`) if I forget to add, then if the code works, it's ok. However, in some prior day I needed to test the code in another machine AFAIR it has Ubuntu 10 or 12. Its compiler complained that there is no `zconf.h`. I wonder whether there is a way to check a machine has `zconf.h`, if not, use `unistd.h`. Can it be done using preprocessors like,

```
#ifdef ITS_IF_CONDITION
    #include <zconf.h>
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
```

Comment: The only `zconf.h` I know is part of zlib. If you want to use `getpid()`, you should just `#include <unistd.h>`, which will work on all unix systems.

Comment: If you find that an existing answer solved your problem, you can accept it. If it's missing just a small bit, you can add it as a comment or just edit the answer. If you came up with a solution yourself, you can post it as a new answer. But please don't edit answers into your question.

Comment: `defined` takes an identifier. After `defined(__has_include` the only possible valid token is `)`, not `(<zconf`.

Comment: Again, I don't know what `zconf.h` you're talking about. If you're talking about zlib, that's for compression, not PIDs.

Comment: What do you mean, "*`zconf.h` is proposed*"? You're the only one "proposing" it.

Comment: Dude, it says in line 1 "*zconf.h -- configuration of the zlib compression library*". That's an internal header used by zlib. You're not supposed to use it in your own code. Also, it's generated dynamically by the `configure` script when you build/install zlib (this is what cyco130 was referring to by "autoconf").

Comment: got it now, thanks @melpomene

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Newer versions of GCC, clang and MSVC compilers implement the [__has_include](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/feature_test) feature. Although it's a C++ 17 feature, I believe all three support it in plain C too.

But the traditional (and probably more portable) way is to check the existence of include files in a config script before the build process. Both [autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Header-Files.html) and [cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CheckIncludeFile.html) have ways to achieve this.

```
#ifdef __has_include
    #if __has_include(<zconf.h>)
        #include <zconf.h>
    #else
        #include <unistd.h>
    #endif
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif
```